# Disqus JSON Javascript Parse Issue in Node

Tags: json, parsing, node.js, disqus

I'm getting the following (str) back from Disqus, JSON expected:

?({"code": 0, "response": {"username": "FakeGrimlock", "about": "ME GIANT ROBOT DINOSAUR. WRITE CODE FOR STARTUP. EAT HUMANS THAT BORING OR STUPID. DRINK COFFEE AND BEER. ", "name": "FAKE GRIMLOCK", "url": "http://WWW.FAKEGRIMLOCK.COM", "profileUrl": "http://disqus.com/FakeGrimlock/", "emailHash": "07bb07626b48f05c093d70fb69ef8a76", "avatar": {"permalink": "http://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/FakeGrimlock.jpg", "cache": "http://mediacdn.disqus.com/uploads/users/437/9401/avatar92.jpg?1313888496"}, "isAnonymous": false, "id": "4379401"}});

so I fix it...

```
str='[' + str.substr(2, str.length-4) + ']'
```

which gives us this:

[{"code": 0, "response": {"username": "FakeGrimlock", "about": "ME GIANT ROBOT DINOSAUR. WRITE CODE FOR STARTUP. EAT HUMANS THAT BORING OR STUPID. DRINK COFFEE AND BEER. ", "name": "FAKE GRIMLOCK", "url": "http://WWW.FAKEGRIMLOCK.COM", "profileUrl": "http://disqus.com/FakeGrimlock/", "emailHash": "07bb07626b48f05c093d70fb69ef8a76", "avatar": {"permalink": "http://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/FakeGrimlock.jpg", "cache": "http://mediacdn.disqus.com/uploads/users/437/9401/avatar92.jpg?1313888496"}, "isAnonymous": false, "id": "4379401"}}]

...which passes at JSONLINT, and then try to get it into an object here...

```
var obj=JSON.parse(str);
```

console.log(obj) displays this:

[ { code: 0,
    response: 
     { username: 'FakeGrimlock',
       about: 'ME GIANT ROBOT DINOSAUR. WRITE CODE FOR STARTUP. EAT HUMANS THAT BORING OR STUPID. DRINK COFFEE AND BEER. ',
       name: 'FAKE GRIMLOCK',
       url: 'http://WWW.FAKEGRIMLOCK.COM',
       profileUrl: 'http://disqus.com/FakeGrimlock/',
       emailHash: '07bb07626b48f05c093d70fb69ef8a76',
       avatar: [Object],
       isAnonymous: false,
       id: '4379401' } } ]

And then it fails here:

```
console.log(obj.response[0])// response is undefined.
```

Testing the obj output in JSONLINT shows an error, which I'm assuming is that the "" were removed by JSON.Parse.

Regardless, I'm not able to access the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple.  Your JSON object is an array (the leading '[').  Try this:

```
obj[0].response
```

Or just don't surround it with brackets to start with...

Comment: omg my brain is fried. Thanks...I had tried obj.response[0]...so basic. ugh! thanks again, sanity restored